# Is it possible to concatenate a column which contains values as number and text with another column in Power Query?

Tags: concatenation, powerquery, m

I'm trying to concatenate a column containing SKUs that don't follow a pattern (some fields with numbers only while others with both text and number) and another column which contains only text. Does anyone know if it is possible to do that in Power Query? Since there is fields with different formats in the first column (e.g. OCI-110; 1354; etc.), none of the methods worked for me.

I've tried the conventional methods to make the concatenation. Perhaps a conditional concatenation could work, however I have no idea about|a M synthax for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add a step to change the entire SKU column to text?

Comment: JSmart325 It doesn’t work because I have other fields in this column with numbers only, so if I change the format of the column to text it will return an error for those fields.

Comment: Please provide some sample data in copyable format.

Comment: Changing a field to text if it contains a number, just makes the number into text